# django updateview return blank template

Tags: django

here is in my models.py:

```
class Segment(models.Model):
    email_segment_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email_segment_status = models.BooleanField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)  
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True) 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.email_segment_name
```

and forms.py:

```
class SegmentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Segment
        fields = ['email_segment_name']
        labels = {
            'email_server_name':('Server Name'),
        }
```

and views:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class SegmentUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Segment
    form_class = SegmentForm
    template_name_suffix = '_update_form'   
    success_url = '/emails/segment'
```

segment_update_form.html:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Update" />
</form>
```

the FormView and DeleteView just works fine, but when I update the form, it response with 200 OK and the page is blank, any ideas?

Comment: What view does the `success_url` point to?

Comment: segment list page:  class SegmentList(ListView):
    model = Segment

Comment: And what is the template for that list view?

Comment: But what does that *contain*?

Comment: It works fine after I restart my mac. I still don't know why this happens.

Answer (score 1):

change:

```
method='post'
```

to:

```
method='get'
```

in segment_update_form.html